# Is there a cleaner, more Grailsy way to write this query?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, eager-loading, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a couple scenarios where I want to retrieve a single `Advertiser` and eager fetch most of its object graph. I definitely don't want to do this by default, so I've been searching for the right way to do this for a single query. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
    Advertiser.createCriteria().get {
        eq('id', id)
        createAlias('foos', 'foos', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('foos.bars', 'bars', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('bars.baz', 'bazzes', CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
    }
```

This works, but I dislike it for a couple reasons.

1. It seems like a very indirect and unintuitive way to say "just join the dang tables please."
2. There is no compile time checking. If the `foos` association didn't exist on an `Advertiser`, the compiler would not care.

Here's how I'd really love to see it work:

```
Advertiser.where {
    id == id
    foos {
        bars {
            baz
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't do any joining; apparently, if you're not actually specifying conditions for that property (`>`, `<`, `==`, etc) it will just ignore you.

What are my options? How can I, at bare minimum, make this more intuitive to read? Looking for the closest to my ideal as I can get.

**Edit**

I've tried some of the suggestions below and things aren't working, and it may be partially because I'm not getting my syntax right. Let's say that I need to eager fetch an additional 1st level association called `whatsits`

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
Advertiser.withCriteria {
    idEq(id)
    whatsits
    foos {
        bars {
            baz 
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
Advertiser.withCriteria {
    idEq(id) && whatsits && foos {
        bars {
            baz
        }
    }
}
```

But different approaches yield different exceptions, strange looking queries, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too far from your first example, but you may or may not find it more intuitive?

```
def result = Advertiser.withCriteria {
    eq('id', id)
    fetchMode 'foos', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'foos.bars', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'bars.baz', FetchMode.JOIN
}
```

Comment: The question uses 1 INNER_JOIN and 2 LEFT_JOINs. FetchMode.JOIN will result in 3 INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DSLs in `createCriteria/withCriteria` as you have used in the `where` clause, they are by default `eagerly` fetched. You get result as a list, so `result[0]` should be it.

```
def result = Advertiser.withCriteria {
    idEq(id)
    foos{
       bars{
          baz{

          }
       }
    }
}
```

After getting the result back you can check whether you have the associations present, that is,

`if(result[0].foos){...}`

**UPDATE**

Refer this [Sample Code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5642307/) for details.

**UPDATE2**

`&&`,`||`,`==` cannot be used in a criteria. They have dedicated DSL's for the same operations like `and{}`, `or{}`, `eq()`. Have a look at [Grails Criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

```
Advertiser.withCriteria {
    idEq(id)
    whatsits{}
    foos {
        bars {
            baz
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to only fetch one object, like `createCriteria().get` does in my example?

Comment: In above case it will fetch only one object since we are fetching against the primary key `id`. Isn't it? You can use `createCriteria().get` to get the same result back as the object itself and not as list of one object.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. I get "No such property: foos for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder"

Comment: Ok then it will be great if we can see all the domain classes and associations.

Comment: I may be having a syntax issue. Please see the update on my question. Thanks!

Comment: Refer this workable [Sample Code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5642307/) for more details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29555/discussion-between-samo-and-dmahapatro)